Are there any disadvantages in controlling a Dahlander motor's speed with a VFD?
I have a single-voltage, dual-speed induction motor with Dahlander connection. A rotary switch is used to select either the low or high speed. The motor specs are:

Voltage: 220V 3-phase, 50Hz
Current: 6.5/9.5 A
HP: 2/3 CV
RPM: 1500/3000 RPM

The motor powers an old (late 70s) combination machine for woodworking. I'd like to now run the motor using a VFD with 220V 3-phase output, using V/f control.
I have two possibilities for controlling the motor speed:

Through the rotary switch: with only two selectable speeds. Since it's a Dahlander motor, I can still use the two winding configurations, one for each speed. First set the rotary switch to either desired speed: low or high. Leave the VFD frequency adjustment always fixed to 50 Hz. Then turn on the motor via the VFD.
Through the VFD: with continuous speed adjustment. The rotary switch is fixed at the high speed position. Speed adjustment is done via the VFD's potentiometer (or an external one). Since VFDs can also be programmed to select fixed speeds, a rotary switch or push buttons could also be used as an alternative to have only two selectable speeds in this setup.

I don't particularly need the fine, continous setting of speeds, the two original speeds (1500 and 3000 rpm) would be enough for my purposes.
My main concerns are for the low speed setting, as I'd like to determine what the best option is (1 or 2) for the most optimal overheat prevention and torque conditions.
I'm tending towards option 2, since it's easier to implement and to operate. If I understand it correctly, V/f control would provide constant torque within this range of speeds. So if torque is not an issue, would there be any disadvantages in the VFD approach (2) vs. the rotary switch approach (1)?

Thank you for your comment. Please note the question does mention that the VFD will be used in both cases. It's more about whether it's better to use one method of controlling the speed vs. the other.

Thanks. "As the motor electrical characteristic change at run-time, I fear the VFD worsen the speed switching transition" => I don't really follow this. Could you please ellaborate?

"You must prevent to actuate the speed switch (or motor transformer) while the VFD run the motor. The VFD could be destroyed." => Already noted on the question (option 1, set speed, then turn on the motor). The VFD I have is an entry-level, open-loop V/f control device. My main concerns are for the low speed setting, to determine what the best option (1 or 2) is for the most optimal torque and overheat prevention conditions.

This double speed motor is a Dahlander type for constant torque load, connection is Delta/Star-Star.
From plate power and speed, you can calculate that rated torque in low speed is 9,5 Nm, and 7 Nm in high speed.
In this graphic you can compare  the torque and current using a VFD up to 3000 rpm in both connections.

Below 2000 rpm, Delta connection can give more rated torque, demanding less current, compared with Y-Y ; but with a speed over 2000 rpm, rated torque will be lower.
So using a single connection (approach 2), in Y-Y case will get less torque in low speed, and more losses in IGBT. In case single connection in Delta, will have more torque available in low speed, more efficient, but in high speed will have limited torque.
Using a switch for Delta/Y-Y at VFD output (approach 1)  can have the advantange of more torque available, less motor current for low speed (less heating in VFD IGBT, more efficiency) in low speed (Delta) ,  and more torque in high speed (Y-Y).
The disadvantage is more complexity: you should interlock pole switching when VFD is running. Also VFD parameter job is more difficult, you need to introduce 2 motors parameters sets (resistance and  inductance of windings are differents , rated speed, rated current...) and with an auxiliary contact of the main poles switch, select which one of the motors parameters set is in operation.

Thanks! Regarding using approach 1 and the parametering for two motor profiles, my VFD has that possibility. It's very basic, but from the relevant parameters that I can set up on each profile one is the overload current at least. It's a very elementary, open-loop V/f VFD. Now for interlocking pole switching while the VFD is running, do you have any ideas on how to implement it?

@KB : interlock can be done using contactors for pole switching, select with push butons and latch the coils. Use a relay connected to a digital output of the drive, disable changing the selection when the Drive is running.

Do you happen to have that spreadsheet available somewhere online? I'd be interested to see how the calculations for the diagrams are done, particularly for the Torque1 curve after 1500 rpm. Thanks!

You can calculate Torque[Nm]=Power[W]30/Pi speed[rpm]; with a speed >1500 rpm (50 Hz), VFD will increase frecuency, but voltage will be constant (not possible to output > 220 V). In this range, Power (V*I), will also be constant,1500 W=2 HP, so Torque will decrease as rpm increases.
